# Authenticate Google JWT in NestJs

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, nestjs, google-authentication

I have a front end application (angular).
I am making a rest call to a nestjs backend.

This rest call needs an bearer token.
I have the bearer token from google.

However when I use it I get Unauthorized.

From my understanding I need to get the keys for google.
I have read that I get the keys from .well-known, however I don't know where this is.

Below is my passport strategy, I have come across and tried a few variations on.

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
    private configService: ConfigService){

super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: '.well=known URI (I think)',
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    const { email } = payload;
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ email });

    if(!user || !user.isActive) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. For some reason it did not work in the cloned repository I was using, but after re-cloning, it worked.

Below is  the implementation.

->'KEYS_URI': This will be the uri that will contain the keys from who you are authenticating the token with. For example: Google - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

->'Issuer': This will be the uri of the issuer. For example: Google - https://accounts.google.com

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
    private configService: ConfigService){

    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: 'KEYS_URI',
      }),
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      issuer: 'Issuer',
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayloadInterface) {

    const { email } = payload;
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ email });

    if(!user || !user.isActive) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```